# How to design android widgets

Tags: android

In android there are some widgets like button etc., Usually when we define a button in xml graphically, it looks in the form, grey colour with black text and some px's of curves. I don't like that design and I want to change it .How can I do that. Please let me know steps.

Thank you :)

Comment: You may have better luck if you make your question much more specific. "Design" is a rather broad concept. Explaining how to "change it" is well beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: you need to create custom button by creating xml for button background

Answer (score 1):

Many visual aspects of Android's built-in widgets can be controlled via Styles and Themes as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) in the official documentation.

If you need more customization, you can create your own subclasses of existing widgets or create your own view classes as described [here](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) in the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

To customize the **look-and-feel and functionality** of any in-built Android widget, you either need to change their style or subclass it.

I would like to give you an example of how to subclass the `Button` widget. You can customize it in every possible way you want.

```
public class MyButton extends Button {

    public MyButton(){
        super(null);
    }

    public MyButton(Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvasObject) {
        super.onDraw(canvasObject);
        int x = 100;
        int y = 100;
        int width = 80;
        int height = 200;
        Paint thePaint = new Paint();   
        thePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        RectF rectangle1 = new RectF(x,y,x+width,y+height);
        canvasObject.drawRoundRect(rectangle1, 10.0f, 10.0f, thePaint);   
    }

}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: How and where can I implement this MyButton class